# Upload csv with multiple relations

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to build relationships between a list of companies (with employee hierarchy) that are partnered together in an ecosystem in addition to investors.  I have 6 columns in my csv for: Company, Investor, Customer (J labeled as a company but for relationship customer), CompanyX (X labeled as a company but for relationship for partner companies), Employee (for employees), and EmployeeL (L for hierarchy).

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///ecosystem.csv' AS line
MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
MERGE (I:Investor {Investor: line.Investor })
MERGE (J:Customer {Company: line.Company })
MERGE (X:CompanyX {Company: line.Company })
MERGE (N:Employee {Employee: line.Employee })
MERGE (L:EmployeeL {Employee: line.Employee })
MERGE (C)<-[:works_for]-(N)
MERGE (L)<-[:reports_to]-(N)
MERGE (J)<-[:Customer]-(C)
MERGE (X)<-[:Partners]->(C)
MERGE (C)<-[:Investor]-(I);
```

Am I over complicating this?  I'm new to Cypher and I'm not sure I'm doing this right and the last time I did an upload similar to this I had to wipe my database clean.  Also how do I input a null value for J/I/C since not all hierarchy's are complete?  When there is a null value, I am unable to upload the csv.

Comment: why are you 3x merging on the same value ? `MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
MERGE (J:Customer {Company: line.Company })
MERGE (X:CompanyX {Company: line.Company })`

Comment: I'm not sure how else to differentiate partners, customers and companies using a single label as Company.  I found that when creating relationships, if a Company's name is both a customer or partner, then it creates separate nodes and the relationship isn't connected.  Do you suggest another way?

Comment: It sounds to me that you're confusing relationships with labels. Try to narrow down your labels to what makes sense for the thing itself in isolation, and then let the relationships to other things speak for itself. For example, :Company seems like a good label, so keep that, but :Customer doesn't really make sense, since this is just a :Company that has a :Customer relationship to another another :Company. And you definitely do not need :CompanyX or :EmployeeL. Also your property names seem redundant. Why not have 'name' be the common property on all these nodes?

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I'll just create another cvs with name and company and I'll create the relation using MERGE (C)<-[:works_for]-(N);
I should probably use the following:

    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///ecosystem.csv' AS line
    MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
    MERGE (I:Investor {Investor: line.Investor })
    MERGE (C)<-[:Investor]-(I);

Once I have that set, how do I build the relations in the excel and in cypher?  I assume I'll have to create a new column as Relations but I'm not sure what to put in there if I have about 150 rows for companies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only three columns in your csv, I would create a query like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///ecosystem.csv' AS line
MERGE (C:Company {name: line.Company })
MERGE (I:Investor {name: line.Investor })
MERGE (N:Employee {name: line.Employee })
MERGE (C)<-[:Investor]-(I)
MERGE (C)<-[:works_for]-(N)
```

You should avoid using birectional directions as `:works_for` and `:reports_to`. Check this [article](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html).

Comment: Thanks.  Any suggestions on how I should build relations in my csv file then reflect that in cypher?  I'd like to build relationships between companies such as partnerships, customers, etc.  Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you can insert a column with the relationship type and upload it using cypher.

Comment: it is possible if you use apoc library with procedure like CALL apoc.create.relationship(person1,'KNOWS',{key:value,…​}, person2)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.  On another note, is it possible to have multiple columns of information on a name node?  For example, Name is John Doe, Position is President of Sales, Located in California, etc.  If so, any suggestions on how to merge that information in a single name node?

Comment: Ask a new question on SO an d maybe upvote the answer here